# How can I manipulate tibbles in my list with R?

Tags: r

I am pretty sure that has been asked previously, but as I am stuck to proceed although the considerable amount of search.
I needed to ask:
18 xlsx files and all are the same structure. Each of size is: 40X7. They belong to different subjects. My first variable/vector is event_number starting from 1 to 40 for each subject/files.
I want to create data frames for each event containing all subjects: so I should have 40 data frames(event_number with 18X7 size(number of subjects X #_of_other variables) in the end.

Any suggestions how can I loop over subjects?

What I did so far was:

```
path <- "my_path" 
url_xlsx <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.xlsx", recursive = TRUE)
read_xlsx_files <- function(x){df <- read_xlsx(path = paste(path, x, sep = "/"))
return(df)} 
df <- lapply(url_xlsx, read_xlsx_files )
df <- as.list(df)
analyze <- function(filename) {
  file_subj <- separate_rows(df[[i]], 1, sep = ",")
  split(file_subj, file_subj$event_number)
}
bb <- lapply(df, FUN = analyze)
```

Actually, I have all tibbles in bb, but I couldn`t proceed to manipulate through the list.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Look up `enframe`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!